# Choose which audio file format to use between Android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, file, audio, format

In my app,I want to make sure user can record his sound and sent to other user to listen to it.
In android platform I choose .amr ,it's not too big and easy to record.

Then I realized I should make sure my ios user can chat with my android user,but .amr seems not support in ios(after v4.3).

So **is there a certain audio file format that can use between android and ios platform**?
Or I have to let my Server to do the Transcoding job?

Comment: .m4a is best to use between both platform.

Comment: At last we use amr. Ios client do the decode job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last we use amr. Ios client do the decode job.

Comment: AMR is no longer supported (≥ iOS 4.3, see supported audio formats in the Apple iOS SDK Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html)

Answer (score 1):

Both android and iOS should be able to handle mp3 files.

You can encode to mp3 on the device using various open source projects (could be a combination of steps).

I would personally go for a server-side encoding/conversion, because too many things can go wrong (especially on all the various Android versions and devices)

Comment: Although I must say it's not always as simple as it sounds ;-)